# Problema .htaccess para endereçamento sem www

Tags: htaccess, http, redirecionamento, redirecionamento-de-url, opencart

Quando digito no navegador

> `phimodasecia.com.br`

meu site/loja entra (é redirecionado) com erro como abaixo:

> `https://www.phimodasecia.com.br/https://phimodasecia.com.br/`

Minha configuração para o .htaccess é

```
# ======== COMEÇA AQUI ========
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
# ======== TERMINA AQUI ========

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^phimodasecia.com.br [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://www.phimodasecia.com.br/$1 [r=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta a flag `L` no primeiro `Rule`, assim:

```apacheconf
# ======== COMEÇA AQUI ========
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
# ======== TERMINA AQUI ========

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^phimodasecia.com.br [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://www.phimodasecia.com.br/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Não precisa de dois `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: certinho, funcionou e solucionou meu problema. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar a flag `L` para interromper o processamento das outras regras. Isso significa que se a regra corresponder, nenhuma outra regra será processada.

O comando é correspondente ao `last` em Perl ou `break` em C.

Use essa flag para indicar que a regra atual deve ser aplicada imediatamente sem considerar regras adicionais.

Exemplo:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^phimodasecia.com.br [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.phimodasecia.com.br/$1 [L,R=301]
```